# How to format NGINX config in browser?

Tags: code-formatting, nginx-config, formatter

Do we have an open source tool to format an NGINX config file in browser or IDE?

I found this one http://nginxbeautifier.com/. But it redirected me to a scam web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found several open source tools that can format NGINX config files

Browser:

- https://nginxbeautifier.online/ Source code https://github.com/nginxbeautifier/nginxbeautifier.github.io

Visual Studio Code:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=raynigon.nginx-formatter. Source code https://github.com/raynigon/vscode-nginx-formatter

Python:

- Source code https://github.com/1connect/nginx-config-formatter